# Using type parameter in anonymous class in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to declare attribute of parametrized type inside anonymous class. This works in Java, in Scala (2.9) however I get compile error:

```
Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
```

This is the code:

```
object DemoFail extends App {
  def it[T <: AnyRef](x: T) = new Iterator[T] {
    var i = x // here is the error
    def next = i
    def hasNext = true
  }
  for (i ← it(int2Integer(4))) println(i)
}
```

I can get it to work by "erasing" types manually:

```
object DemoOK extends App {
  def it[T <: AnyRef](x: T) = new Iterator[T] {
    var i: AnyRef = x
    def next = i.asInstanceOf[T]
    def hasNext = true
  }
  for (i ← it(int2Integer(4))) println(i)
}
```

So the question is: why can't the compiler do it for me ?

Comment: By adding a public variable to your iterator, you create a structural type that is a subtype of Iterator. It'll work if you change i to a private variable.

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how could I miss such an obvious solution.

Comment: @Kris: please respond below with an answer so I can properly accept it.

Comment: @Kris So this means that any access to `i` would happen through Java reflection, right?

Comment: I think that internal accesses would not use reflection, but you'd have to look at the bytecode to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a public variable to your iterator, you create a structural type that is a subtype of Iterator. It'll work if you change i to a private variable.

Answer (score 1):

I am, unfortunately, not sure why this doesn't work.  But here is an alternate workaround that avoids casts:

```
def it[T <: AnyRef](x: T) = {
  class Forever extends Iterator[T] {
    var i = x
    def next = i
    def hasNext = true
  }
  new Forever
}
```

Comment: This works because it avoids the structural type I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to avoid the structural return type:

```
object DemoFail extends App {
  // The same with an explicit (non structural) return type
  //                       vvvvvvvvvvvvv
  def it[T <: AnyRef](x: T): Iterator[T] = 
    new Iterator[T] {
      var i = x // no more error
      def next = i
      def hasNext = true
    }
  for (i ← it(int2Integer(4))) println(i)
}
```

Indeed, method `it` on object `DemoFail` does not have an explicit return type. Hence this return type is inferred by the compiler.

Here, as you are overriding existing members and adding a new one to `Iterator[T]`, the inferred return type of the method `it` is a structural type of the form `Iterator[T] with Object {def next: T; var i : T; def hasNext: Boolean}` (as an IDE like IntelliJ can suggest).

Thus you are defining a method whose return type is a structural type that uses an abstract type of this same method. This is what bothers scalac (structural type with same method's abstract type).